# How to get retune code of function when using log redirection in Shell?

Tags: python, shell, return-code

In My shell scripts1, It works.：

**test1.sh**

```
python main.py
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
exit
fi
```

**test2.sh**

```
python main.py 2>&1 | tee log.txt 
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
exit
fi
```

Script 2 is failed. How could I get the return code of python-call `main` in test2.sh？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question for POSIX Shell, and AFIK, there is no way to achieve this in a POSIX Shell. However, many other shells do have a feature, which allow this.

For instance, if you could use bash, you can use `PIPESTATUS`, as was suggested here already. If you go for Zsh, there is a similar array named `pipestatus`.

If you want to go for `ksh`, you don't have an equivalent feature, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463581/kornshell-equivalant-of-pipestatus) is a discussion how to deal with this problem in Korn Shell.

Comment: Sorry for this incomplete information. I can use bash and `PIPESTATUS` . Thank a alot ::::::)))))))

Answer (score 2):

If you use more commands in one line, you need to use the `PIPESTATUS` to get the proper return code for each command.

For example:

**Python code:**

```
import sys


def exit_with_code():
    sys.exit(5)


exit_with_code()
```

**Shell script:**

```
python3 test.py  2>&1 | tee log.txt
echo "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}"
```

**Output:**

```
5 0
```

It means the return code of `Python` script is 5 and the return code of `tee` is 0.

Comment: @milanbalazs : PIPESTATUS is not defined in [Posix Shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right! But the questioner didn't mentioned POSIX in his question! But this problem can be solved with temp files in POSIX.

Comment: @milanbalazs: Actually he did. He tagged it as _Shell_, and the definition of this tag says that unless another tag explicitly mentions a specific shell, a POSIX compatible solution is asked for.

Comment: I agree! Sorry, it was my mistake! I will pay more attention to tags. On the other hand, the questioner uses `Bash` so he can use the `PIPESTATUS`! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the redirection outside of the `if` and also avoid the antipattern.

```sh
if ! python main.py; then
   exit
fi 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

(See [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern))